# TextMate for iOS development

Tags: xcode4, textmate

Alright, after spending nearly two years with Xcode, I'm finally sick and tired of the monstrosity that is Xcode 4. Xcode 3.* had it quirks but it was way faster, crashed much less and was much more fun to work with in general. As of now, my Xcode removes all syntax highlighting whenever it feels lazy, crashes if I turn off disable break points, start playing with the app and then turn them on again. A couple of weeks ago, it randomly failed to update from the App Store and I was stuck trying to figure out how to fix it. At this point, every version that Apple releases is making it harder and harder to tolerate.

I use TextMate for rails development (I'm a very new to it however),
but again, at this point, I'm so frustrated with Xcode that I'm willing to go through the initial pain of setting it up if it works better in the longer run. Although I'm ok with writing a few build scripts, I don't want it to get painful, so I was wondering if someone did it already.

Comment: Well, i've been refraining myself to bash the toy, but i must concur. I have tried (with delight) JetBrains' AppCode during its beta phase, and am ready to jump ship for the next project. I'll look into TextMate as another possibility, thks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate has a bundle for XCode (I'm not sure if it ships with TM anymore, but GetBundle would find it).

You can certainly build XCode projects using this command. I know in the past I've also set breakpoints in XCode from TextMate and ran things, but I'm not sure if those were parts of the standard bundle or something I added myself with Applescript.

For a related SO question, check out: [getting XCode 4.3 to build with the XCode.tmbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313638/cant-build-xcode-4-project-from-textmate)